# How can I make an <input> hover CSS work only if the <input> does not have focus?

Tags: html, css

I have an input field CSS like this:

```
input {
   background: white;
   border: 1px solid #bbb;
   box-shadow: none;
}

input:hover {
   background: white;
   border: 1px solid #999;
   outline: none;
   box-shadow: none;
 }

input:focus {
   outline: none;
   box-shadow: none;
   border: 1px solid #555;
}
```

My problem is that when I give the input focus the hover effect takes over if my cursor is also over the `<input>`.

Is there a way I can make the hover effect work only when the input does not have focus?

Comment: Unable to reproduce http://jsfiddle.net/VpqAH/

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem: http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/y8y7Z. Sounds to me like a specificity issue, could you please include the actual CSS you use if what you've posted isn't already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the code you've provided I can't reproduce the issue, which leads me to believe that this is a *specificity* problem. (If you're not sure what that is, I wrote a blog post about specificity earlier today: *[**What the heck is specificity?**](http://blog.jamesmdonnelly.com/what-the-heck-is-specificity/)*)

With the code you've provided, both `input:hover` and `input:focus` have a specificity of `011`. As long as `input:focus` is included *after* `input:hover` in your stylesheet then the `focus` style will always override the `:hover`.

[**First JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/VYxLM/1/).

If your `:hover` has an extra selector, its specificity will be higher than the `:focus` selector. For instance:

```
input.example:hover { ... }
input:focus { ... }
```

[**Second JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/VYxLM/).

With an extra `class`, the `:hover` selector above now has a specificity of `021` and will override the `:focus` selector which still has a lower specificity of `011`.

Ensure your `:focus` selector has higher specificity and your `:hover` will not apply when the element is focussed.

Comment: I will look more into this later. I did try !important and it fixed the problem. Now time for me to sit down and research your comments. Thanks for your input. Will update the thread later.